# existence solution-order 2 exercice

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let the equation $$u''+a(x)u=0$$ where $a \in \mathcal{C}^1([0,+\infty[)$ 
how we can prouve the existence of an solution for this equation? 
thank's for help

Comment: There should be some initial condition, or $u=0$ would solve the equation.

Comment: okay! so it's suffisant to say that $u=0$ is an solution fo this equation. We don't need for an theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v(x) = (u(x), u'(x))^T$, $f(v,x) = (v_2, -a(x) v_1)^T$. Then the equation above is equivalent to the equation $v' = f(v,x)$. We see that $\|f(v,x)-f(w,x)\| = \sqrt{(v_2-w_2)^2+a^2(x)(v_1-w_1)^2} \leq \sqrt{1+a^2(x)} \|v-w\|$.
If we let $L_M = \max_{x \in [0,M]} \sqrt{1+a^2(x)} $, then we see that $f$ is Lipschitz in $v$ with rank $L_M$ for $x \in [0,M]$.

Hence for any initial condition $v_0 = (u(0), u'(0))^T$ and for any $M>0$, then by the Picard–Lindelöf theorem there exists a unique solution to the differential equation on the interval $[0,M]$ passing through the initial condition $v_0$. Since $M$ is arbitrary and the solution is unique, it follows that the solution is defined on all of $[0,\infty)$.

**Note**: Suppose $\phi_{v_0}$ is a solution to the system starting from initial condition $v_0$. Then since the system of equations is linear, we have $\phi_{v_0} = [v_0]_1 \phi_{e_1} + [v_0]_2 \phi_{e_2}$. So, it is only necessary to note that $\phi_{e_1}, \phi_{e_2}$ are defined on $[0,\infty)$, then the general solution is given by the preceeding formula.

Comment: hi cooper.hat, but hear the question is to prouve the existence of solution (not unicity beacause we haven't the initial data). The question is to prouve that the equation admits an one least solution. There exist an theorem to prouve it? or we say only that because $u=0$ is an solution, so the equation admits an one least solution?

Comment: Well, any solution must have an initial condition. You can pick an arbitrary one if you want. You could also notice that the ODE is linear, so you need only solve for initial conditions $(0,1)^T, (1,0)^T$ and then you have all solutions. This may be what the question is looking for...

Comment: I added a relevant note to the answer.